# R: Convert consensus output into a data frame

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I'm currently performing a multiple sequence alignment using the 'msa' package from Bioconductor. I'm using this to calculate the consensus sequence (msaConsensusSequence) and conservation score (msaConservationScore). This gives me outputs that are values ...

e.g.

***ConsensusSequence:***

```
 i.llE etc (str = chr)
```

(lower case = 20%+ conservation, uppercase = 80%+ conservation, . = <20% conservation)

***ConservationScore:***

```
 221 -296 579 71 423 etc (str = named num)
```

I would like to convert these into a table where the first row contains columns where each is a different letter in the consensus sequence and the second row is the corresponding conservation score.

e.g.

```
 i     .      l     l    E
 221   -296   579   71   423
```

Could people please advise on the best way to go about this?

Thanks
Natalie

Comment: Have you tried using `msaConservationScore`? You can specify which conservation matrix to use and it returns an output exactly as the one you asked for

Comment: The output I get with the msaConservationScore does give me what I want, but not in a way I can use it as it is a vector. When I try to convert it to a data frame, it only gives me the numbers, not the consensus alignment. I really require a data.frame with row1: consensus, row2: conservation score.

Do you know how I can get my data into this format? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For what you have said in the comments you can get a data frame like this:

```
data(BLOSUM62)
alignment <- msa(mySequences)
conservation <- msaConservationScore(alignment, BLOSUM62)

# Now create the data fram
df <- data.frame(consensus = names(conservation), conservation = conservation)
head(df)

    consensus conservation
1         T          141
2         E          160
3         E          165
4         E          325
5         ?          179
6         ?           71
7         T          216
8         W          891
9         ?           38
10        T          405
11        L          204
```

If you prefer to transpose it you can:

```
df <- t(df)
colnames(df) <- 1:ncol(df)
```